# ERROR: You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just write "pip install" and the cmd show me this message

C:\Windows\system32>pip install
ERROR: You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")

Comment: `pip install` by itself does nothing, hence the error.  It should be `pip install <package name>`.  What are you trying to install?

Comment: did you see `pip help install`?

Comment: Please show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask .

Answer (score 0):

```
After "pip install", you should write the name of a package,
like "pip install numpy"
Its format is "pip install <package name>"
This is help description :

> Usage:
  pip install [options] <requirement specifier> [package-index-options] ...
  pip install [options] -r <requirements file> [package-index-options] ...
  pip install [options] [-e] <vcs project url> ...
  pip install [options] [-e] <local project path> ...
  pip install [options] <archive url/path> ...

Description:
  Install packages from:

  - PyPI (and other indexes) using requirement specifiers.
  - VCS project urls.
  - Local project directories.
  - Local or remote source archives.
```